# Did Sayanacharya believe in the authority of Ithihas and Puranas?

Tags: scripture, vedas, puranas, pramana

As you might be knowing, Sayana is one of the classical commentator on Vedas. My question is what was his opinion on the authority of Ithihas and Puranas? Did he believe in them?

Comment: He must be believing. Traditional Acharyas usually believe in all scriptures. I hv Yajurvedas with Sayana's commentary. Thr he alludes to Puranic stories on many occasions to explain some of the Vedic Mantras. But those ref can not be used to answer here..

Comment: @Rickross i think those references can be used to prove he believed in authority of Puranas. Even he says each and every name of Rudra in Sri Rudra has a story in puranas and ithihasa.

Comment: @Rickross I heard from someone that he actually gave ritualistic interpretation (Mimamsa) of the Vedas, and rejected Puranas, Ithihasa, Dharmasastras and even philosophy of the Upanishads. Is it true?

Comment: I don't know what he thought abt Upanishads but  he refers to Puranic stories while explaining some Vedic mantras and that only goes to show that he believed in the Puranas at least... @NaveenKick

Comment: @Rickross Then please write an answer. As the destroyer said,  those references can be used to prove that he believed in authority of Puranas

Comment: Also, regarding Upanishads, we can look at what Sayana commented on Isha and Brihadaranyaka Upanishads, as they are part of Samhitas and Brahmanas.

Answer (score 5):

Sayanacharya often alludes to Puranic legends to explain certain Vedic Mantras. This I have noticed at some places of the YajurVeda books I have.

In the book [Rig Veda Mandala 5 (R.L.Kashyap)](https://archive.org/details/RigvedaMandala5KashyapR.L.) the author/translator also confirms the same.

The author says in his foreword (p.26):

> Unlike Sayana Acharya, we do not resort to Puranic legends to explain
>   the mantra-s.

[image]

So, Sayana Acharya did had belief in the Puranas.